# Serializing custom exception object

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

It's a .net core project running on a Mac. I've a custom Exception class that I'm serializing as JSON as output in case of an error.

```
  public class HttpException : Exception {
    private readonly int statusCode;

    public HttpException() {}

    public HttpException(int statusCode, string message) : base(message) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public int StatusCode {get {return this.statusCode;}}
}
```

Code related to json serialization

```
Exception exception = (Exception)serviceRequest.ResultData;
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();  
DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Exception));  


// it fails here
dataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, exception);  


byte[] json = memoryStream.ToArray();  
memoryStream.Close();  
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json, 0, json.Length));
```

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Service.Model.Exceptions.HttpException' with data contract name 'HttpException:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Model.Exceptions' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)

**Edit**

Trying to use System.Web.Extensions but have squiggly lines.

[image]

Comment: `// it fails here` with what error?

Comment: You didn't ask a question or state what the issue is.

Comment: Matt it's not duplicate. The issue was with `new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(HttpException));`, I used `Exception` before. this brings another question, how can I make it generic because system can throw different kinds of exceptions, do I've to narrow down to `typeof` each?

Comment: Use Json.Net `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exception);` it will work

Comment: @Eser I wish but I can't fall outside with 3rd party libraries, only native implementations because of some requirements.

Comment: @App2015 even M$ uses it in MVC. So maybe you can loose your requirements :)

Comment: @eser you're thinking of Web API.  MVC still uses `JavaScriptSerializer` by default, not JSON.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wish but I can't fall outside with 3rd party libraries, only native implementations because of some requirements.

You can include the System.Web.Extensions library and use *JavaScriptSerializer*

```
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = ser.Serialize(exception);
```

But as I said in comments, I would prefer [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Yes I'd love to use this, how do I get this library, it's showing squiggly lines and I'm using .net core on a Mac, and asp.net application.

Comment: @App2015 You introduce new requirements at every step. Now it is `.net core`.  Shit..... Forget my comments/answers, and learn how to ask a complete question

Comment: is there a way to do nit pick instead of serializing the whole object, how about serializing one or two string variables to output stream?

Comment: turns out, Newtonsoft.Json is already there with .net core, and I override `GetObjectData` to nit pick the data.

Comment: @App2015 I thought you wouldn't allowed to use 3rd party libs :)

Comment: I'd not add intentionally, it's prepackaged, that changes things

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.Extensions is not supported in .Net Core, but you can use the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package. One of these two methods should do the trick:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string value)
```

I encountered a similar issue when porting unit tests from .Net 4.6.1 to .Net Core.

On a side-note, if you are getting any strange runtime exceptions, look for instances of JavaScriptSerializer and replace them with corresponding Newtonsoft.Json methods.